# Why do Google Analytics reports display aggregated values in header that are not the sum of all rows?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

For my new Google Analytics API I am just doing some testing, if I am pulling the data correctly.

However, I encountered several confusing issues doin so. For example, when I look at my custom report, I tend to have a result for users ("Nutzer") that is not the sum of the affected rows, while for new users ("Neue Nutzer") it is exactly the sum of rows (=12.654):

[image]

Also when I am adding the dimension PagePath I am getting the same correct result for new users, but when I sum up the users, I am getting like 52.000 as a result for the same date range as above. How does this happen?

Comment: This is a multi dimensional database.   Not a relational database.    You need to make the same request that the website is making if you want the api to return the same results.  Summing values from two different requests will rarely result in the answer you expect.

Comment: You may have better luck understanding how Google analytics works on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each row in a report, the Total Users metrics in GA4 is the number of distinct users. Let's say the report is for the dimension `Date` and metric `Total Users`. One user could have visited your site on multiple dates. That users contributes `+1` to the `Total Users` metric in multiple rows, but in the total, that user contributes `+1` only once. GA4 uses [Reporting identity](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10976610) to differentiate and de-duplicate users.

A user is only new during their first session. In this report, I believe each new user is only contributing `+1` to one row. This allows the sum of the New Users rows to match the total.

Thanks, 
Brett Sneed 
The Google Analytics Team

Answer (score 2):

The sum does not match up, and it is intended, because what you get as total is the count of single users over the analysis period, while rows lists user count on the dimension basis (picking the dimension day for instance, one user, counted as one above, could have made a visit on day 1 for instance -therefore incrementing 1 on day 1 - and another visit on day 3 - also incrementing users count for day 3)